# PyQt5 List and Timer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

tldr: I want to add a timer that can be triggered with a start/stop button and reset with a another button to a list-like interface.

I'm working on building a list with timers. The purpose is to keep track of the amount of time spent on particular tasks/items. At the moment, I have a functional list and a button that pops up a dialog box allowing the user to input a string that populates the list.

I'm looking for ideas on how to incorporate a timer. Maybe it could be a two column list. Then we could have a boolean type for the timer to pause and start it. And maybe a button to reset the timer.

Later on, I'd like the timer data to be persistent so that you could maintain the times after shutting down the app.

Here's a possible look:

[image: Mockup]

Any help with the UI would be appreciated as well. My code is [here](https://github.com/ali-alsabbah/HausTimer).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QInputDialog, \
QListWidget, QApplication)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.btn = QPushButton('New Item', self)
        self.btn.move(5, 5)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.list = QListWidget(self)
        self.list.move(115, 10)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 385, 215)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input dialog')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):

        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter item:')

        if ok:
            self.list.addItem(str(text))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The important parts of a question should not depend on an external link because it can be broken making useless for future readers and invalidating your question, and your code is an important part.

Comment: Could you explain me better, what do you mean by a timer? How should your application be viewed? you could show a scheme,

Comment: @eyllanesc I added a picture to the post

Comment: When does the Timer start?

Comment: Is one single timers active or can they be active? I mean that you can explain yourself better.

Comment: @eyllanesc One single timer is active at a time. All the timers are independent. The timer starts when the start button is pressed.